# NSCoding data not saved when returning to the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

I don't understand why `previousArrays` returns `(null)`, I would like to save a class containing a bezier path and its color.

The code : (after `touchesEnded` is called, a path is created and saved in memory. When I come back to the app with `initWithCoder`, `previousArrays` is `(null)` ) :

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if ( !(self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) return nil;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSArray *previousArrays = [SaveData loadDict];
    NSLog(@"previousArrays : %@", previousArrays);//***HERE*** : return (null)

    for ( id object in previousArrays){
    //for ( NSDictionary*dict in previousArrays){
        NSLog(@"obj %@", [[object class] description]);

//...

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:myPath];//nscoding compliant
    DataForPath *firstPath = [[DataForPath alloc] init];
    firstPath.path = bezierPath;
    firstPath.colorInArray = @(currentColor);
    NSLog(@"touchEnded, firstPath : %@", firstPath);
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"firstPath":firstPath};

    [SaveData saveDict:dict];
}     


@implementation SaveData

static NSString* kMyData = @"data1";

+ (void) saveDict:(NSDictionary*) dict{
    NSLog(@"saving data...");

    //retrieve previous data
    NSData *previousData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kMyData];
    NSMutableArray *previousArray = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:previousData] mutableCopy];
    [previousArray addObject:dict];

    //add new data, and save
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:previousArray];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:kMyData];

    //NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
}

+(NSArray*) loadDict {
     NSLog(@"loading data...");
    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kMyData];
    NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    return array;
}


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import UIKit;

@interface DataForPath : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath* path;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *colorInArray;

@end


@implementation DataForPath

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder{
    if ( !(self = [super init]) ) return nil;
    self.path = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"path"];
    self.colorInArray = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"colorInArray"];
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.path forKey:@"path"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.colorInArray forKey:@"colorInArray"];
}
```

Also, is there a way to see what is in the NSUserDefault, such as a "prettyjson" format? `-dictionaryRepresentation` returns some figures like that  `<124d1f>`

Comment: Does your `DataForPath` class implement `NSCoding`?

Comment: @Chris hi Chris, yes, the code is below, when you scroll down, DataForPath : NSObject <NSCoding>

Comment: You should also conform to the [`NSSecureCoding` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSSecureCoding_Protocol_Ref/index.html) available in iOS 6 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use this : `if ( previousArray == nil ) ...`

```
NSMutableArray *previousArray = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:previousData] mutableCopy];
if ( previousArray == nil ) previousArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer so its placed at the top of the answer list. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448) on Meta.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked `saveDict` method for `previousArray` == `nil` ?, Because before you saved something you have nothing in userDefaults

Comment: sorry for the old comments, it works, I forgot to say "if previousArray is nil, alloc init a new one" in "saveData". I was adding an object to a null object. Tricky. Thanks for the message.

Answer (score -1):

Not enough information.

Objects can be converted to and from data if they conform to the NSCoding protocol. You have to write code for both the encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder methods that saves all your object's properties.

If you are un-archiving an object that you saved with encodeWithCoder and one of it's properties is not loading then there is most likely a problem with your encodeWithCoder method.

Post the header for the class you're trying to encode, all of the encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder methods, and information about the properties of your object that you are encoding.

Also post the code that converts your object to data and saves it, and provide a description of when/how it is saved.

Comment: sorry for the old comments, it works, I forgot to say "if previousArray is nil, alloc init a new one" in "saveData". I was adding an object to a null object. Tricky. Thanks for the message.

Comment: @Paul, I'm glad you fixed your problem. You should probably post an answer to your own question and accept it so people know it's solved, and to help other readers.

Comment: *"Objects can be converted to and from data if they conform to the NSCoding protocol..."* - he should also conform to the [`NSSecureCoding` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSSecureCoding_Protocol_Ref/index.html) available in iOS 6 and above.